# Thunderbird gmail IMAP error

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, ssl, imap

I am trying to setup a gmail account in the Thunderbird and I get the following error:

[image]

Here are the IMAP settings (I have tried it with imap.gmail.com as well and it doesn't work):

[image]

Here are the SMTP settings (I have tried it with smtp.googlemail.com as well and it doesn't work):

[image]

I do have IMAP enabled on my gmail.  I enter full user name (username@gmail.com).  Port 993/995, 465 are open, Windows Firewall is disabled, I am running Thunderbird on Windows 7.

I used the most recent Thunderbird and downgraded to previous versions in the hope that maybe that was an issue, but the same issue keeps occurring.

Please, help!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First your imap server info is incorrect, see attached.
Also, your outgoing (smtp) should be TLS not SSL. Also Thunderbird should auto-configure all of this for you on any recent version with you just entering your email address and password.

Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server - Requires SSL
imap.gmail.com
Port: 993
Requires SSL:Yes

Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - Requires TLS
smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465 or 587
Requires SSL: Yes
Requires authentication: Yes
Use same settings as incoming mail server

Full Name or Display Name: [your name]
Account Name or User Name: your full Gmail address (username@gmail.com). Google Apps users, please enter username@your_domain.com

Email address: your full Gmail address (username@gmail.com) Google Apps users, please enter username@your_domain.com

Password: your Gmail password

Comment: In addition it may be needed to switch on the support for lesser secure applications (be sure to read the page): https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: See also discussion here: https://superuser.com/questions/855676/why-does-google-call-thunderbird-less-secure