# Thunderbird does not like Google?

Tags: firefox, email, thunderbird, google-search, email-client

The Mozilla's mail client Thunderbird, that was one day a great mail client, that is suffering from functional (exchange integration missing) and design problems (especially the search is awful) does not include "Google" among the possible application's search engines.

Google, by the way, [remarked that Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/855676/why-does-google-call-thunderbird-less-secure) would not correspond to the "latest security standards".

Does Mozilla plan to seriously upgrade his mail client, or should the Thunderbird users look for something better?

I understand the question is subjective, but I am rather asking about the objective opinion on Thuerdenbird's future as mail client than a subjective opinion about how good it is.

Comment: This question is asking for an opinion and will be closed.  But, here is a FYI:  Mozilla does not include Google as a search engine, because they feel Google violates users' privacy.  You can always add Google search to Thunderbird as a plugin.

Comment: This question starts with a premise that is opinion that may not be shared, and information that is no longer factually correct, and asks for opinion and speculation.  This is a poster child of an off-topic question.

Comment: @Keltari: they could put a warning, but let google search engine as choice... I am forced to search on shitty search engines just because someone from Mozilla's guys does not like Google...

Comment: I am asking about the objective future of the client (development plans or news), if someone knows, not about personal feelings about the product itself.

Comment: @Serge as i stated in my previous comment, you can use google search in thunderbird

Comment: @Keltari is not the subject of the eventual possibility of using Google via third party application or add-ins, is rather the subject of Mozilla's "I do what I want", without consulting the user's opinion. If such an add-in was created, so people are not comfortable with the default behavior. How do you imagine today a search engine list without "Google"? any commercial product would do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the answer you linked, it is stated that the OAuth bug in Thunderbird is fixed, so the main issue of Thunderbird being insecure for Gmail is fixed by now.

Mozilla stopped actively developing Thunderbird a few years ago and it is now a community project, which means that the development will probably slow down even more over time. Personally, I would recommend just using the Gmail web interface.

Comment: I understand, but I wouldn't ever use Thunderbird just for Google mail. I have also exchange and other mails I would like to have in a single place.

Comment: If you're fine with using Thunderbird for now and are not missing features, just use it. The most critical security patches will probably still be fixed in the future.